# Find hashes in a Ruby string

Tags: ruby, parsing, functional-programming

I have a string that looks like this:

```
greetings = <<-GREETINGS
[{a: "hello", b: "goodbye"}, {a: "guten tag", b: "auf wiedersehen"}]
GREETINGS
```

How can I split this string, so as to return an Array of the Hashes?

Comment: Although there's certainly a way to do it, I have to ask _why_ you have a string like this, and not something easily parsable like JSON?

Comment: It's a TMUX buffer of some errors that were thrown when running a script. It comes back weirdly formatted and I figured the best way to deal with it would just be to wrap the whole thing in a string and parse out the hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trust the source (and *only* if you trust the source, which is probably not true):

```
data = eval(str)
```

If you do not (which should be close to 100% of cases), then you can use the [`parsr` gem](https://github.com/byroot/parsr/)

```
data = Parsr.literal_eval(str)
```

You could also write your own grammar, but... why? :)

Comment: Watch out for the eval patrol, with their pitchforks and torches... Curiously, I've found that nobody complains if I use `instance_eval` instead of `eval`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `instance_eval` with a string argument is the same as `eval`, as far as the danger is concerned. `instance_eval` with a block is safe.

Comment: My point: `instance_eval(greetings)` doesn't provoke the same dire warnings that `eval(greetings)` does.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: My point: if I see you instance_evalling a string, your ass is grass. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse(greetings.gsub(/(\p{Alnum})+:/, '"\1":')).
     map { |h| h.transform_keys(&:to_sym) }
  #=> [{:a=>"hello", :b=>"goodbye"},
  #    {:a=>"guten tag", :b=>"auf wiedersehen"}]
```

The steps are as follows:

```
str = greetings.gsub(/(\p{Alnum})+:/, '"\1":')
  #=> "[{\"a\": \"hello\", \"b\": \"goodbye\"}, {\"a\": \"guten tag\", \"b\": \"auf wiedersehen\"}]\n"
```

```
arr = JSON.parse(str)
  #=> [{"a"=>"hello", "b"=>"goodbye"},
  #    {"a"=>"guten tag", "b"=>"auf wiedersehen"}] 
arr.map { |h| h.transform_keys(&:to_sym) } 
  #=> [{:a=>"hello", :b=>"goodbye"},
  #    {:a=>"guten tag", :b=>"auf wiedersehen"}]
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or more alphanumeric characters in capture group 1 followed by a colon". The `\1` in `gsub`'s replacement string is replaced with the contents of capture group 1.

See [JSON::parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse), [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [Hash#transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys).

Comment: Be aware that this will fail if a value contains a word followed by a colon: e.g. `{name: "Punctuation: Colon and Semicolon" }`.

Comment: @Amadan yes, it’d be safer to `/(\p{Alnum})+:(?=\s*"[^"]+")/`.